# Is the Rama Setu pilgrimage "equally effective" for all pilgrims irrespective of their dwelling places?

Tags: shiva, belief, rama, india, pilgrimage

The [Skanda Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana30.html),Brahma Khanda,describes the greatness of [Rama Setu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rameswaram) as follows:

> In the Brahma Khanda of Skanda Purana, Suta Maha Muni addressed a
>   Conclave of Rishis and narrated the significance of Setu Bandhan/
>   Tirtha as also of Rameswara Kshetra which were visualised and built by
>   Sri Rama;  **even visioning these Places would bestow Mukti from
>   Samsara.**  Emphasising the Unity of Vishnu and Siva, the Three Sacred
>   Places viz. Setu (bridge), Rameswara Linga and Gandhamadan Mountain
>   constitute the composite identity. .....
>
> **If one lies down on Setu’s banks and sticks the sand on the body, the
>   number of as many sand particles would absolve as many Brahmahatya
>   sins!** The touch of the wind on one’s body from the mid-banks of Setu
>   would pardon ten thousand ‘Surapanaas’ (drinking intoxicants). If one
>   does ‘Snaan’ at the Tirtha and seeks relief on somebody else’s favour,
>   then too the sins of the proxy beneficiaries are washed off. **The Five
>   Brahmahatya sinners, who spoil the roads, prepare food for them only,
>   abuse Brahmanas and Sanyasis, accept the food of a Chandala and sell
>   Vedas are also excused by the holy bath at Setu Tirtha**...There are
>   several Tirthas on either side of the Setu, but most significant are
>   twenty four. The most important ones are Chakra Tirtha, Betala varada
>   Tirtha, and Paapavinashana Tirtha which were famous. Then there are
>   Sitasarovar Tirtha, Mangala Tirtha and Amritavaapika. Again, there are
>   Brahmakund, Hanumakund, Agasthya Tirtha, Rama Tirtha, Lakshmana
>   Tirtha, Jaya Tirtha, Lakshmi Tirtha, Agni Tirtha, Chakra Tirtha, Siva
>   Tirtha, Shankha Tirtha, Yamuna Tirtha, Ganga Tirtha, Gaya Tirtha, Koti
>   Tirtha, Saadhyamrita Tirtha, Maanasa Tirtha and Dhanushkodi Tirtha.
>   These are only illustrative Tirthas which are all Sin demolishers.

So,without doubt, Rama Setu (the Rameswaram Kshetra) is indeed a a very holy pilgrimage kshetra that is capable of demolishing all kinds of sins and giving the pilgrims even mukti from Samsara.

**But will its effectiveness be the same for all people irrespective of their dwelling places?**

For example, suppose a visitor is from Gujarat and another one from Tamil Nadu.Will the visits of both of them to the Rama Setu bear the same fruit assuming all other relevant factors remain the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently **NO.**

The Parashara Smriti says:

> 73. **The visit to the Setubandha has been declared to be the form of expiation proper for a person whose residence is to the north of the
>       [Vindhya hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vindhya_Range).** This is the opinion of Parasara.(Parashara
>       Smriti,Chapter 12,sloka 73)

In other words, this verse implies, that for a person whose residence is in Tamil Nadu(which is to the south of Vindhya), a visit to Rama Setu pilgrimage bears no or little fruits !!

Well,this came  to me as a big surprise.

That's why i posted this question so that i may get the other perspectives as well from  other Scriptures.

Comment: I don't think it has no fruit for South Indians, just less fruit.  Like it may not cleanse all sins unlike in the North Indians case.  In any case, I think the issue is that a pilgrimage should require you to go a long distance so that your arduous effort will be richly rewarded.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have added bear less fruit in my answer..But the Parashara verse seems to imply that it is not an effective pilgrimage at all for the south indians.

Comment: @Rickross is there a reason why this is so?

Comment: @KVickneshvara I don't know the reason but there must be some..Keshav had pointed to a rational reason but i don't think that is the actual reason..